# Como cambiar el formato en que se muestran los numeros de un arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

no entiendo como cambiar el formato de los numeros que se muestran en la columna "Total" de la siguiente tabla.
[image]

La idea es que el formato de cada numero de cada fila se vea asi, por ejemplo asi: 656.745.

Este el metodo que uso para la lista.

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                if (i > 0) {
                    if (currentRow.getCell(0)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(1)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(2)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(3)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(4)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(5)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(6)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(7)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(8)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(9)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(10)
                            != null) {
                        debtFileTO.setCustomerID(currentRow.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
                        debtFileTO.setCustomerNombre(currentRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                        debtFileTO.setCustomerEmail(currentRow.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());
                        debtFileTO.setCustomerPhone(currentRow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                        debtFileTO.setTotalDeuda(currentRow.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue());
                        debtFileTOs.add(debtFileTO);
                        debtFileTO = new DebtFileTO();
                        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript(mensajewall);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar NumberFormat, DecimalFormat para darle formato a la presentación de ese valor

Comment: Me podrias decir como, esque soy nuevo.